# adding jquery features to <img> tag in html file

Tags: jquery, html, image, jquery-draggable

I am working on html5 app development using Jquery n css.
i am creating a image under a div tag as shown below

```
<div id="FrontRight">
<img id="imgFrontRight" src="../images/car.jpg">
</div>
```

Now i want this image -imgFrontRight to be draggable with the following attributes

```
$( "#imgFrontLeft" ). draggable
({ 
    axis: "y" ,
    containment:[0,152,0,290] });
```

I have achieved this when the image is dynamically created in my jquery javascript file. However i want the same thing to happen when img tag is used to create a image in a html file.

Kindly help with this.
Thanku !!

Comment: How can an img tag be used to create an image in an html file?

Comment: <img> would add a image then we add attributes to it as mentioned in the question. Now i am trying to add draggable feature in <img> tag like < img draggable={ axis : "y", containment:[x1,y1,x2,y2] }> This might be wrong. Could you please tell me the right syntax for this. Or any other alternative way to achieve this

Answer (score 0):

If you are creating the elements dynamically, then after the dynamic element is added to the `dom` you need to make draggable by calling `jQeury.draggable` for it.

```
$('<img src="" />').appendTo(x).draggable({....});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/HE3Le/)